# Angular: In a service: watch for changes in another service

Tags: angularjs

I have one service depending on another service. When a method on the other service gives a different result (than previously), I would like a property on my main service automatically to change (and then this change will automatically, via controller-view-binding, get to the view).

Was this question understandable? How can this be achieved? I could have the controller do the watching, but perhaps it is possible to have my main service itself watch for changes in the depending service (save me of having a watch in each and every controller)?

Answer (score 0):

Add the other service as a dependency into your main service and add following function there too:

```
$scope.watch( $otherService.getValue, function (newValue, oldValue) {

    alert("value changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    $scope.propertyToChange = ....

});
```

GetValue is a function in the other service that returns the value that should be watched. If the result of this function changes, the watcher will be triggered.

I can't test that snippet right now, sorry. But I hope it will help you.

Comment: But in my main service, is there such a thing as $scope? Services has properties and methods, but $scope?

Comment: Oh yes ... right. Then put that `$scope.watch` into your controller and call your main service within that function. So the workflow would be: second service change -> controller detects that -> controller informs main service.

Comment: But then I would have to repeat this $scope.watch in all controllers (that uses this service)... But ok, if there is no way avoiding that...

Comment: This solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806600/angularjs-watch-inside-a-service suggests a $rootScope that can be added to the service. You may try this first, before editing all your controllers. Hope that helps.