# How to watch array or object change in service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have service in my angular app. This service provide access to array with some operations (access is provided to many controllers, they all need to watch this variable).

But how to watch changes from this service? It does not have $scope, and I don't know, where to find $watch?

Here is my service code:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('something')
        .factory('MasterService',['$http', function($http){
            var service = this;
            var data = {                
                operations: [] // this array need to be accessible from controllers
            };

            $http.get('some/url').success(function(data){
                // here we mofidy array with loaded from server
                data.operations = angular.copy(data.operations);
            });

            return {
                // controllers will receive operations via this method
                getOperations: function () {
                    return data.operations;
                }
            };
        }])
})();
```

How to watch operations variable from within this service? I need to add something like that:

```
        operations.$watch(function(){
            //make some actions with operations
        });
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806600/angularjs-watch-inside-a-service

Comment: Can you explain why you need to watch from within the service? At any rate you need to have scope to watch.

Comment: You can just *create* a scope, for your $watching pleasure, can't you?

Comment: Can you give an example of why you need to watch changes from the service?

Comment: When something changed in controller (somebody added new thing or changed), in service i need to update master data (it depends on that data) (maybe I need one more controller???).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*$watchers are useful when your data changes outside of angular, and it's pretty redundant to use it within angular app as digest cycle already have watchers, you better check our logic.* 
Use this approach so that you don't even need $watcher

```
(function(){
    angular.module('something')
        .factory('MasterService',['$http', function($http){
            var service = this;
            var data = {                
                operations: [] // this array need to be accessible from controllers
            };
            //ommitted
            return {
                // controllers will receive operations via this method
                operations: data.operations
            };
        }])
})();
```

and in controller

```
$scope.operators = MasterService.operators;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **controller** you could $watch a function which returns the service data:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return MasterService.getOperations();
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  // do something with newVal;
});
```